# how to override a library’s use of an inline loader

Tags: webpack, webpack-dev-server, pdf.js, pdfjs-dist

A library I depend on (in this case, pdfjs) is using the worker loader inline via `var PdfjsWorker = require('worker-loader!./build/pdf.worker.js');`

I really want to configure the worker loader to just inline this worker so I can still use the webpack development server.... I have the following configuration not being matched:

```
    module: {
        rules: [
          {
            test: /\.worker\.js$/,
            use: { 
                loader: 'worker-loader',
                options: { inline: true }
            }
          }
        ]
      }
```

When I edit node_modules directly (gross) and update the line to `var PdfjsWorker = require('./build/pdf.worker.js');` everything works and it is PERFECT.... is there a way to basically FORCE an option for *all* usages of a given loader even if the loader is being specified inline? Or a way to perhaps literally rewrite this line of code or SOMETHING I can make webpack do so I can essentially get what I want out of this?